# Set intersection is wrong

Tags: arrays, swift, set, intersection

I am creating a program that works with geographic information.  I have data that contains what geographic units touch each other.  The function that fails is intended to add neighboring units to an array based on population (for example, it starts with a unit, then adds the most populous neighboring unit to the array, and then adds the most populous unit that touches one of the units in the array, and continues this until it reaches a population limit).  The way I am doing this is using a for loop, and then using an array of the total units that have been sorted by population.  I then find the index of the first (and therefore most populous) neighbor using the intersection between the neighbors of the units in the array and the neighbors of each unit in the array of total units.  The following is my code :

```
 func createDistrict () {
         if useBoard.isEmpty == false {
        useBoard.sort(by: {$0.population > $1.population})
        var maxPop = useBoard.first!.population
        district.removeAll()
        district.append(useBoard.first!)
        useBoard.removeFirst()
       
        for i in 0...useBoard.count - 1 {
            if useBoard.indices.contains(i) {
            if useBoard[i] == nil || district.map({$0.population}).reduce(0,+) > districtMax {
            break
            }
            } else {
                break
            }
            useBoard.sort(by: {$0.population > $1.population})
            var superArray:[Precinct] = []
            district.forEach { (z) in
                superArray += z.neighbors
                Array(Set(superArray))
            }
            var nextPre = useBoard.firstIndex { (l) -> Bool in
                Set(l.neighbors).intersection(Set(superArray)).isEmpty == false
            }
            if nextPre == nil {
                break
            }else {
                var temporary = Set(useBoard[nextPre!].neighbors).intersection(Set(superArray))
                var newString = ""
                var newTemp = Array(temporary)
                for t in 0...newTemp.count - 1 {
                    var next = useBoard.firstIndex { (k) -> Bool in
                        k == newTemp[t]
                    }
                    newString.append("\(newTemp[t]) (\(next)), ")
                }
                print("\(useBoard[nextPre!].precinctID) (\(nextPre!)) touches \(newString)")


            }

        district.append(useBoard[nextPre!])
                useBoard.remove(at: nextPre!)
        }
    }
        district.forEach { (p) in
            print("\(p.precinctID)")
        }
    }
```

In this function,   `var nextPre = useBoard.firstIndex { (l) -> Bool in Set(l.neighbors).intersection(Set(superArray)).isEmpty == false}` is used to find the index of the most populous neighbor. However, when I test it using `print`, I get an incorrect output.  In the following excerpt, the values in the parentheses are just the indices and don't really matter.  The output:

```
2104 (8) touches 1987 (Optional(710)), 2676 (Optional(1591)), 
2387 (10) touches 2105 (Optional(2140)), 
2274 (11) touches 2273 (Optional(52)), 2386 (Optional(236)), 
2275 (14) touches 2276 (Optional(22)), 2105 (Optional(2138)), 2273 (Optional(51)), 
2276 (21) touches 2389 (Optional(1638)), 2273 (Optional(50)), 2274 (nil), 2275 (nil), 2277 (Optional(2771)), 2386 (Optional(234)), 
2067 (35) touches 2404 (Optional(76)), 2212 (Optional(944)), 
2406 (40) touches 2404 (Optional(75)), 2070 (Optional(1771)), 
2440 (42) touches 2212 (Optional(942)), 2388 (Optional(497)), 2441 (Optional(1364)), 
2273 (46) touches 2386 (Optional(230)), 2276 (nil), 2064 (Optional(384)), 2275 (nil), 2105 (Optional(2133)), 2274 (nil), 2387 (nil), 
1795 (55) touches 1891 (Optional(1212)), 
1908 (41) touches 2638 (Optional(2568)), 1869 (Optional(474)), 
2404 (70) touches 2212 (Optional(938)), 2070 (Optional(1766)), 2069 (Optional(365)), 2068 (Optional(581)), 1743 (Optional(2453)), 2405 (Optional(2442)), 2387 (nil), 2105 (Optional(2130)), 2284 (Optional(2792)), 
2736 (70) touches 2548 (Optional(1314)), 2420 (Optional(1305)), 
1798 (52) touches 2419 (Optional(270)), 
1907 (45) touches 1912 (Optional(1611)), 2737 (Optional(2082)),
```

As you can see, the neighbors are off by 1.  For example, 2104 is the first unit.  Then 2387 touches 2105, which is 2104 + 1.  Then 2274 touches 2386, which is 2387 - 1.  Then 2275 touches 2105, which is 2104 + 1.  The `.intersection` should find the first unit that touches the units in the array, yet it finds the first unit that touches a unit's name + 1.  I have no idea how this is occurring, as the geographic units are stored in a custom object, not an integer or any other number variable.  Here is the custom object:

```
class Precinct {
    var precinctID:String
    var population:Int
    var neighbors:[Precinct]
    init(precinctID:String, population:Int, neighbors:[Precinct]){
        self.precinctID = precinctID
        self.population = population
        self.neighbors = neighbors
    }
}

extension Precinct: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Precinct, rhs: Precinct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.precinctID == rhs.precinctID && lhs.population == rhs.population && lhs.neighbors == rhs.neighbors
    }
}

extension Precinct: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return precinctID.hashValue ^ population.hashValue
    }
}

extension Precinct: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(precinctID)"
    }
    
    
}
```

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: @matt Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @BenA. Hashability is a heuristic for equality. If you know the hash value of an object, you don't have to compare it 1 by 1 against every other object, only those with the same hash value as it. But if you have a broken implementation of hashable/equatable, then this scheme doesn't work, and you get undefined behaviour like this.

Comment: In this case, it's because your equatable implementation considers `neighbors`, but your washable implementation does not.

Comment: P.S. don't use XOR as a makeshift hash function for combining values. Use the new [`hash(into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/2995575-hash), and the system will use a proper hasher to mix values.

Comment: PPS, don't write code like `for i in 0...useBoard.count - 1`. https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

Comment: @Alexander Would you mind explaining this further?  I'm not sure I fully understand it.

Comment: Suppose you had to find eggs in the super market. Would you go through every item in the market, and read its box to see if its eggs, and repeat until you found eggs?

Comment: @Alexander What would the proper way of doing it be?

Comment: @matt How should I implement `hashValue`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195097/discussion-between-alexander-and-ben-a).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that you are removing elements of useBoard while at the same time iterating over useBoard. You are printing the indices `"\(newTemp[t]) (\(next)), "` and then five lines later removing an index; before repeating the process. While you can change the values of a collection you are iterating over, never change the size of the collection at the same time.

A first step may be to copy useBoard before running the outer loop. Keep it constant so that you iterate over all of its contents but use the copy for all of your logic. I have trouble following the intent of your code.

As far as the hash, that is **not** your problem. However it is not ideal. Swift provides a default hash that is almost always better. Just allow Swift to synthesize its own algorithm by changing that extension to this.

```
extension Precinct: Hashable {}
```

There are a couple of issues. Please remove the call to sort useBoard within the outer loop. That has no effect because useBoard was already sorted before entering the loop. Also `Array(Set(superArray))` is not doing anything for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Copying useBoard and changing how it iterates didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I can't speak directly to what has been done but I would suggest simplifying your test data set to the smallest possible size with the simplest values and using the debugger to step through your code. Understand every value as you go through your loop and watch for the first problem occurrence. The Debugger is your friend.